# AWS EMR Performance issues while copying the intermediate processed data by Spark to the Target S3

Tags: amazon-emr

Currently I am using AWS EMR for Data processing. S3 is being used as the Landing zone and Final processed Data. Final processed data from S3 is getting loaded in Redshift for Customers to Run Analytics.

- Daily I receive 100 small files of small KBs and MBs (2-3MB max). The data needs to be present in Redshift in 15 mins as per SLA, once the source file is available in landing zone. The Final Bucket for the Orders table is 800GB.
- SCD Type 1 is implemented
- pySpark is used for processing. Data cleansing is done in 2-3 mins
- **Spark** creates an intermediate folder for data processing from which we are wring the final processed data to another S3 Bucket
- This process takes almost 45 minutes even for small data of KBs. The code is below
- `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic')`
- Checked the normal data copy is taking 3-4 mins between folders under same bucket
- 5 Node transient cluster is being used (r5.4x Large)

  ```
    df.write.format("parquet").partitionBy("src", "hash_value").mode("append").save(path)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

FOllowing were the tuning done in the last couple of Days. The loading time is reduced from 1.30Hrs to 30 Mins

1. used R type instance. It provides more memory compared to M type instances at same price
2. used coalesce to merge the files in source there were many small files.
3. Check the number of mapper tasks. The more the task, lesser the performance
4. we had some unwanted count of data. Removed the same
5. used EMRFS
   6.used below in the emr config file. Previously we used

   {
   "classification": "spark-env",
   "properties": {
   "spark.executor.memory": "16g",
   "spark.driver.memory": "4g",
   "spark.driver.cores": "4",
   "spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "4g",
   "spark.executor.cores": "5",
   "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "4g"
   }

Now I am using the below

```
{
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
       "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  }
```