# How to speed up write csv file in aws spark( scala )?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am doing data preprocessing using spark(scala) on aws.
Through preprocessing, the size of the sample data has been reduced from 5GB to 2.7GB, and I want to finally store it in the aws S3 bucket.

The problem is that saving to S3 is too slow.
As you can see in the picture, it takes 536 seconds.

When preprocessing with Hadoop pig and performing "-getmerge", it is stored in the loot device of the master node at a speed of approximately 2~3GB/sec, and finally, when store in S3 through aws cli, the speed of approximately 120MB/sec.

The original data is about 640GB, and it is too slow to store the preprocessing results. Is there a way to save faster like getmerge in HDFS environment?

I want to store it in S3 bucket as one csv file.

[image]

Comment: write without `coalesce(1)`

Comment: If coalesce(1) is excluded, won't it be saved in a split state?

Comment: @topologie It would save multiple csv files within the directory if you use coalesce and it would be much faster and also you could read faster. If you don't want to go with default partitions like 200 you could reduce it to something like 24 or 48 using Coalesce. Why do you want one large csv file?

Comment: Please refer my [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198670/aws-emr-performance-issues-while-copying-the-intermediate-processed-data-by-spar). This will help

Comment: @ Nikunj Kakadiya Thank you for your answer. The reason I don't want to save it in a separate directory. It also has a private local server like nas, so it is convenient to have it as a single file.